# Contact Deletion - How to prevent contacts from reentering a Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contact, contactbuilder, contact-deletion

I intent to delete a number of contacts from "All Contacts" list. At the same time, I have Journeys, which had contacts injected more than 6 months in the past and I would like to prevent them from reentering the Journey once the Sales Cloud Synch is reestablished.

The contact will under certain criteria enter the Marketing Cloud but should not enter previous Journeys in which he/she has been injected into before.

Is there a way after a Contact Deletion, to prevent contacts from reentering a Journey once they are synchronized once more?

Thank you, looking forward to feedback.

Comment: why are you deleting contacts you are just going to re-sync?

Comment: And, what do you mean by, "after a contact deletion"? If you're using the SDK then once you delete a contact the SDK will become disabled.